# Why does my call to Postman mock server not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am trying to test a web API in C# that will consume an external service.

I wanted to test that the calls I am making to the service are working, so I created a mock server using Postman.

I created a mock response to a GET method:

GET `{mockServerUrl}/search` will return the JSON:

```
{
  "Message":"Request worked"
}
```

When I make the call on Postman and on my browser, the mock server works just fine.
When I make the call from my code, the code returns the following exception:

> *Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream*

What could be the problem with calling the server from my code?

Here is the code that I am using to make the call:

```
 var responseHttp = _httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu, I followed the instructions on that page, but still received the Exception "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream"